# Where would I store a CSS file in Openshift v3?

Tags: css, openshift

I am looking for some instructions on how to manage CSS files in Openshift v3.  In Openshift v2 this was easy - just put things in the `/static` directory.  But in v3 this is not specified. I managed to get some ideas from [this blogpost on migrating a Django install](https://blog.openshift.com/migrating-django-applications-openshift-3/), but that refers to setting up a parallel WSGI process just for this, which I couldn't quite understand.

My system is just a simple Python webapp that doesn't use any framework at all.  In that case, how would I serve CSS files in a way that a browser would know where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog post you mention is not setting up a parallel WSGI process. It is using `mod_wsgi-express` as the WSGI server for your application and the same web server processes are also handling static file assets. You would use similar process as what the post describes, albeit with slight change if the static assets are not at a sub URL.

1: Add `mod_wsgi` to `requirements.txt`.

2: Have your static assets in a sub directory called `static`.

3: Have your WSGI application entrypoint be in `wsgi.py`, with the WSGI application callable called `application`. Do not run a builtin WSGI server so make sure execution of one is guarded by a `__main__` check so not run when code file loaded by mod_wsgi.

4: Add an `app.sh` file containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=""

ARGS="$ARGS --log-to-terminal"
ARGS="$ARGS --port 8080"
ARGS="$ARGS --document-root static"

exec mod_wsgi-express start-server $ARGS wsgi.py
```

The `--document-root` is used to specify where static assets are. If a request matches a static file in that directory it will be used, otherwise the request is routed through to your WSGI application.

Using `mod_wsgi-express` is the easiest option here. If you use other WSGI servers which do not support hosting static files, then you would need to use a WSGI middleware such as WhiteNoise to handle hosting the static files.

Comment: Thank you! I wish this was spelled out in the Openshift v3 documentation somewhere...

Comment: The problem is that the Python S2I builder isn't opinionated like it was in V2, where it had a default of Apache/mod_wsgi and would host files in certain directory as static files. In V3 you have to choose your WSGI server and so for things like static file hosting you have to worry about configuring the WSGI server (if supported by it) to host the static files also. Alternatively you use WhiteNoise WSGI middleware which can work on any WSGI server.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions, which is also a standard practice is to make the static files like images/css/js etc available through a CDN. And CDN delivery add a lot of performance improvement to the application.

Steps are

1) Host the CSS on github (or any free repo) open source (with only you as project author)

2) Access it via free CDN (content delivery networks) service like `jsdelivr`

Once hosted, you could access the CSS from python (or any script) like:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/user/repo@version/mycss.css
```

Comment: Though Graham Dumpleton answered my question more directly, this answer is actually more convenient (in most circumstances, I imagine...)